# subquery with top 1 and more than equal to using Linq

Tags: c#, linq

My sql query is as below.

```
select st.kProductVersionPlatformFrom, st.kProductVersionPlatformTo, pv.kProduct, pv.nId, * 
from vSysTable st
left join vProductVersion pv on st.kProductVersionPlatformFrom = pv.nId  
where 
st.kProductVersionPlatformTo >= (select top 1 nid from vProductVersion where kProduct = 2
                                 and kProductVersionPlatform = 87 order by nId desc)
```

I am trying to convert it to Linq but cant find way to use greater than equal to

```
var systemTableList = (from sysTableEntity in _sysTableEntityRepository.AsQueryable()
                       join versionEntity in _productVersionRepository.AsQueryable() on
                           sysTableEntity.ProductVersionPlatformFrom equals versionEntity.Id
                           into leftjoined 
                           from joinedsysVersionTable in leftjoined.DefaultIfEmpty()
                           where (from versionEntity in _productVersionRepository.AsQueryable() 
                                  where versionEntity.ProductEntityId.Equals(2) && 
                                 versionEntity.PlatformProductVersionEntityId.Equals(87) 
                                  orderby versionEntity.Id descending 
                                  select versionEntity.Id).Take(1).Contains(sysTableEntity.ProductVersionPlatformFrom >= 87)
                       select new { sysTableEntity});
```

But it gives me error near the Contains keyword that "The type argument cannot be inferred from usage"

What to use here instead of contains? I also tried using Where but still doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because subquery

```
select top 1 nid
from vProductVersion
where kProduct = 2
and kProductVersionPlatform = 87
order by nId desc
```

is not correlated, you can use it separately, and then its value use in your main query. Also, are you sure, the query always will return value (not null)?

```
var nid = from versionEntity in _productVersionRepository.AsQueryable()
where versionEntity.ProductEntityId.Equals(2) && 
versionEntity.PlatformProductVersionEntityId.Equals(87)
orderby versionEntity.Id descending
select versionEntity.Id).First();
```

Then use this:

```
var systemTableList =
     from sysTableEntity in _sysTableEntityRepository.AsQueryable()
       join versionEntity in _productVersionRepository.AsQueryable()
     on sysTableEntity.ProductVersionPlatformFrom equals versionEntity.Id
           into leftjoined
     from joinedsysVersionTable in leftjoined.DefaultIfEmpty()
     where ProductVersionPlatformTo >= nid;
```

Comment: what if the top 1 query returns null?

Comment: @AshReva This you must tell me.

Comment: i didnt realised it. Sorry about it. Its ok if returns me 0 records but should not throw any error

Comment: @AshReva If the first query returns null, what must be in `ProductVersionPlatformTo >= nid`?

Comment: @AshReva Then you can use `FirstOrDefault()` instead of `First()`.

Comment: Thanks so much. +1 for your efforts